# Is this an appropriate way of collapsing and restoring content in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this simple grid with a `ListView` occupying the leftmost column:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  x:Name="leftColumn"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Width="2"
                  Background="#FF4B4B4B" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                  MouseDoubleClick="GridSplitter_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    <ListView x:Name="lvSubjects" Background="#FF2E2E2E" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And this is my code that allows me to collapse and restore the leftmost column and its contents to the original state:

```
private void GridSplitter_MouseDoubleClick(object sender,
                                           System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (leftColumn.Width != GridLength.Auto)
    {
        lvSubjects.Width = leftColumn.Width.Value;
    }

    leftColumn.Width = GridLength.Auto;

    if (lvSubjects.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        lvSubjects.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        lvSubjects.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Note that I am forced to do the whole width routine prior to collapsing or restoring, due to the fact that width of the column changes from `Auto` to a static number when its been re-sized with `GridSplitter`.  This method is not very refined, and depending on how you do it, may not function all that well. Example: If you drag the `GridSplitter` all the way to the left, double click and then drag it out, `ListView` will not expand.  I did not feel like developing it much further until I find out if I should be doing this at all.  It dawned on me when I finished this portion.

My question is this: Should I be doing what I'm doing here or should I be using an `Expander`?  I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel, but due to the fact that I've never done collapsible panels, this felt like a natural way of accomplishing it.

Comment: Your doubt is justified. When there exists a control(Expander), then why are you reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an expander would be cleaner and I think more intuitive for the users.
But if you also need the column width to be changeable, you would still need the GridSplitter.

```
    <Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  x:Name="leftColumn"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Expander Grid.Column="0" IsExpanded="False" ExpandDirection="Left" 
              Collapsed="Expander_Collapsed_1">
        <ListView x:Name="lvSubjects" Background="#FF2E2E2E" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="120"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Expander>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Width="2"
              Background="#FF4B4B4B" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

If the splitter was used after expanding, you can reduce the column width when the item is colapsed by setting it back to Auto in the colapsed event:

```
    private void Expander_Collapsed_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        leftColumn.Width = GridLength.Auto;
    }
```

You could also do this via Style Trigger if want to avoid code-behind.
If you don't like the expander arrow icon and want to replace it (e.g. by a vertical line), you would need to create a custom control template for it.